# Android : How to asynchronously download data and update Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app which displays real time transport timetable data. I download the data in a subclass of AsyncTask. All works fine up until here. I now want to implement a functionality where I will read any outages on the network and display it above the timetable data.

I can subclass AsyncTask once again to make the http request and get the data. I have tried to pass the data back to the calling class from onPostExecute and my app is unable to display the outages. I stepped through the app and found that my data is being returned to me after I set the adapter for timetable data.

Is there a way to accomplish this task simultaneously or I have to wait for one task to finish before starting another.

Comment: Post your code for the AsyncTask.

Comment: try to rephrase your question. Or give some code to understand your problem.